# python decode email from base64

Tags: python

hello iam using python script to fetch a message from a specific address mail seems everything work fine but i have a problem with the printable result is a base64 code.
i want to decode the result to get the decode message when do the final result with print, pls help!!
already thanks

the code used.

```
# Importing libraries 
import imaplib, email 

user = 'USER_EMAIL_ADDRESS'
password = 'USER_PASSWORD'
imap_url = 'imap.gmail.com'

# Function to get email content part i.e its body part 
def get_body(msg): 
    if msg.is_multipart(): 
        return get_body(msg.get_payload(0)) 
    else: 
        return msg.get_payload(None, True) 

# Function to search for a key value pair 
def search(key, value, con): 
    result, data = con.search(None, key, '"{}"'.format(value)) 
    return data 

# Function to get the list of emails under this label 
def get_emails(result_bytes): 
    msgs = [] # all the email data are pushed inside an array 
    for num in result_bytes[0].split(): 
        typ, data = con.fetch(num, 'BODY.PEEK[1]') 
        msgs.append(data) 

    return msgs 

# this is done to make SSL connnection with GMAIL 
con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url) 

# logging the user in 
con.login(user, password) 

# calling function to check for email under this label 
con.select('Inbox') 

# fetching emails from this user "tu**h*****1@gmail.com" 
msgs = get_emails(search('FROM', 'MY_ANOTHER_GMAIL_ADDRESS', con)) 

# Uncomment this to see what actually comes as data 
# print(msgs) 


# Finding the required content from our msgs 
# User can make custom changes in this part to 
# fetch the required content he / she needs 

# printing them by the order they are displayed in your gmail 
for msg in msgs[::-1]: 
    for sent in msg: 
        if type(sent) is tuple: 

            # encoding set as utf-8 
            content = str(sent[1], 'utf-8') 
            data = str(content) 

            # Handling errors related to unicodenecode 
            try: 
                indexstart = data.find("ltr") 
                data2 = data[indexstart + 5: len(data)] 
                indexend = data2.find("</div>") 

                # printtng the required content which we need 
                # to extract from our email i.e our body 
                print(data2[0: indexend]) 

            except UnicodeEncodeError as e: 
                pass
```

THE RESULT PRINTED

'''

aGVsbG8gd29yZCBpYW0gdGhlIG1lc3NhZ2UgZnJvbSBnbWFpbA==

'''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use the base64 [module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) to decode base64 encoded strings:

```py
import base64

your_string="aGVsbG8gV29ybGQ==" # the base64 encoded string you need to decode
result = base64.b64decode(your_string.encode("utf8")).decode("utf8")
print(result)
```

Edit: encoding changed from ASCII to utf-8

Comment: I would suggest encoding/decoding as utf-8.

Comment: work like a charme thank you bro i was stuck on there for few days

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find all encoded places (can be Subject, From, To email addresses with names), the code below might be useful. Given contentData is the entire email,

```
import re, base64
encodedParts=re.findall('(=\?(.+)\?B\?(.+)\?=)', contentData)
for part in encodedParts:
  encodedPart = part[0]
  charset = part[1]
  encodedContent = part[2]
  contentData = contentData.replace(encodedPart, base64.b64decode(encodedContent).decode(charset))
```